# Is there anything similar to Wamp Server?

Tags: php, mysql, apache, wamp

I would like to know if anyone knows about any program similar to WAMP Server; all-in-one containing PHP, MySQL, Apache?

I am targeting Windows OS.

Comment: LAMP? *chuckles to self* :) Whats wrong with WAMP? I think Zend Server might be a solution for you.

Comment: Do you mean WampServer? I generally think of WAMP as more of a configuration than a singular piece of software.

Comment: For other platforms then or? LAMP? MAMP? XAMPP?

Comment: I am looking for any program similar to WAMPServer and should run on Windows too.

Comment: Zend Server (CE) is a nicely packaged WAMP stack.

Answer (score 1):

Viewing the different WAMP distributions as packages of 3 separate applications and foundations to download different versions and plugins for those packages, you might also try Microsoft's Web Platform Installer.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using Xampp for a while, it's free and works like a charm: **https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html**