# Wamp or an other local host server to develop PHP on a windows environment?

Tags: php, mysql, apache, wamp

I'm used to WAMP, but I've experienced some issues lately on the windows 7 OS.

So I wondered if there are other or better local host servers that I can use?

In my case it's for PHP and MySQL development.

Comment: WAMP is great, most ppl i convert from xampp agree. Get youself toad too http://www.quest.com/toad-for-mysql/ What are the issues ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What WAMP server is the best?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3077554/what-wamp-server-is-the-best)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-windows.html) (comes bundled with PhpMyAdmin, and some other stuff), but you might also want to consider [Zend Server CE](http://www.zend.com/en/products/server-ce/) which I've not tried.

Also, see [Anything Similar to WAMP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2364893/anything-similar-to-wamp) on this site.

Answer (score 0):

I've had no problems whatsoever with [**XAMPP**](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-windows.html) (also Windows 7).

Answer (score 0):

There are other WAMP stacks available. Personally, I use [xampp](http://www.apachefriends.org) on Windows 7 without problems, but also have a custom build and IIS/PHP on the same machine. Debate on which is better is likely to lead to flame wars

Comment: I didn't realise this issue was so contentious.

Comment: @thirtydot - choice of stacks for Windows can be almost as contentious a subject as programming language wars

Answer (score 0):

I also experienced this problem on win7.
In my case it was skype who was blocking port 80 somehow. Because I only work on localhost in development face I changed apache listening port in httpd.conf.

Worked for me

I dont think xamp or wamp matter in your case because you have the same apache and mysql anyways.

Comment: I don't even have skype installed, and in Wamp there is a service to check on port 80. And the answer I get is that the port is indeed used by the server (apache and PHP).

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative that I've used in the past is [EasyPHP](http://www.easyphp.org/).  A bonus to EasyPHP are the modules for WordPress, Drupal, Joomla, and other eCommerce or Forum applications.  You can also install EasyPHP onto a USB drive and take it to any computer/workstation you are using.